# What the meaning of "vertices induce hyperedges" in hypergraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I don't understand what's the meaning of the word "induce" regrading hypergraphs.
For example, "3 vertices induce 2 hyperedges".

I would be glad if you could draw it and explain the meaning of the word.

Edit:
I saw the term in the following article, page 2, the second point of Conjecture 1:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w39zlg08piiwi9d/DominationIn3Tournaments.pdf?dl=0

> The domination number of a 3-tournament such that any four of its
>   vertices induce at least two edges with the same tail is bounded by a
>   constant.

Comment: I don't know about hypergraphs, but "induce" usually means "give in a canonical way". For instance, in standard graphs, a subset of vertices _induce_ a subgraph, by taking those vertices and _all_ edges between those vertices from the original graph. There are many other examples from different fields of mathematics.

Comment: Please edit your question to state where you saw this usage and include more of the surrounding context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertices in hypergraphs induce hyperedges in the same way that vertices in graphs induce edges.

That is, an *induced* subgraph of a (hyper)graph $G$ is a subgraph that includes an edge $e$ of $G$ whenever all vertices of $e$ are included. In particular, the subgraph $G[S]$ induced by a vertex set $S$ is the unique induced subgraph which has vertex set $S$: its edges are all the edges of $G$ contained in $S$.

A slightly-informal phrase such as

> any four of its vertices induce at least two edges with the same tail

that doesn't talk about induced subgraphs directly is meant to unpack to something like

> any set of four vertices induces a subgraph that contains two edges with the same tail.